# Bloquear o acesso as rotas do vue js caso não esteja logado

Tags: javascript, laravel, api, vue.js

não estou conseguindo bloquear as rotas estão passando normal sem a autenticação

Estou desenvolvendo um Dashboard e me veio a duvida de como proibir que acessem as rotas se não estiverem logados, com isso, pensei em algumas soluções que usuariam localStorage, mas, nenhuma é uma solução certa.

Qual seria a maneira correta de fazer isso? vi que muitas pessoas possuem essa duvida, e não consegui uma solução para isso.

```
  export default [

  {
    path: '/',
    // Relative to /src/views
    name: 'home',
    view: 'Dashboard',

  },
  {
    path: '/cliente-index',
    name: 'Clientes',
    view: 'Clientes',



  },
  {
    path: '/sistema-index',
    name: 'Sistemas',
    view: 'Sistemas',
    meta: { 
      requiresAuth: true
  }

  },
  {
    path: '/sistema-pastas/:id:descricao:path_padrao',
    name: 'sistema-pastas',
    view: 'Pastas',
     meta: { 
      requiresAuth: true
  }
  },
  {
    path: '/versao-index',
    name: 'Versões',
    view: 'Versao',
    meta: { 
      requiresAuth: true
  }
  },
  {
    path: '/usuario-index',
    name: 'Usuarios',
    view: 'Usuarios',
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: '',
    view: 'Login',
    meta: { 
      guest: true
  }

  },
  {
    path: '/cliente-sistema/:id',
    name: 'Cliente Sistema',
    view: 'ClienteSistema',
  },  

]


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('jwt') == null) {
            next({
                path: '/login',
                params: { nextUrl: to.fullPath }
            })
        } else {
            let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
            if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.is_admin)) {
                if(user.is_admin == 1){
                    next()
                }
                else{
                    next({ name: 'userboard'})
                }
            }else {
                next()
            }
        }
    } else if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.guest)) {
        if(localStorage.getItem('jwt') == null){
            next()
        }
        else{
            next({ name: 'userboard'})
        }
    }else {
        next() 
    }
})
```

Comment: O problema está no código acima? Com exceção de salvar o adm no localStorage, o que eu não recomendo, o bloqueio de rotas que você fez sentido. O que eu complemento é com bloqueio via interceptor com axios e middleware no back-end. Se quiser posso responder com um bloqueio de rotas, com interceptor e exemplo de middleware no back-end padrão (node ou php).

Answer (score 0):

Você primeiro precisa no seu state ter uma propriedade  para ser setada quando o usuario entrar no sistema após isso precisa adicionar o sessionStorage no store

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso seria bem fácil de hackear, basta editar o storage usando as ferramentas do desenvolvedor